# Access to Class properties with interface object

Tags: c#, collections

Just for my curiosity,

If i have

```
ICollection<string> collection = new List<string>();
```

then i suppose "collection" will have access to only those properties which are declared in ICollection interface or its ancestors interfaces. Thats what OOP's said.

But in actual we have access to all properties of List. Why?

Hope i am not asking some stupid question here. Is my assumption is wrong.

EDIT: Let me try what i wanna to say

```
public interface myInterface {
        public void InterfaceMethod();
    }
    public class MyClass : myInterface
    {
        public MyClass()
        {
        }
        public void InterfaceMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("InterfaceMethod called");
        }
        public void AnotherMethod() {
            Console.WriteLine("AnotherMethod called");
        }
    }

public class Program
{
    private static IContainer Container { get; set; }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        myInterface myObject = new MyClass();
        myObject.InterfaceMethod();
        myObject.AnotherMethod(); //Now myObject is not aware of AnotherMethod, which is correct
    }
}
```

Comment: Show some example what do you mean by `But in actual we have access to all properties of List. Why?`

Comment: This is a generalization, but you can think about ICollection<T> as of an interface built around T[], i.e. an array of T. Would you wonder why a T[] object allows you access to all Ts it holds?

Comment: in visual studio, just write dot next to collection and you will see all methods listed there, but on F12 over ICollection you will see few methods.

Comment: No you don't, you only see methods/properties of ICollection and IList, just try to call IndexOf, or RemoveAt of IList interface

Comment: i know it should. but i have access to ElementAt, FirstOrDefault like methods

Answer (score 0):

`ICollection<string>` inherits from `IEnumerable<string>`, maybe you are confusing properties which are shared across both since `List<string>` also inherits from `IEnumerable<string>`

```
ICollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>,IEnumerable
```

and

```
List<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IList, ICollection, IEnumerable
```

Comment: To be pedantic.. `ICollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>,IEnumerable`